# How do I use apt-file with the Debian installation media?

Tags: debian, apt

I have several servers that cannot reach the Internet and want to use apt-file on them.

I've extracted the contents of the five DVD ISOs (for Lenny/amd64) and can use apt-update/apt-upgrade via HTTP. What further steps do I need to take to get apt-file working?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Removed original post:

What steps have you taken with apt-ftparchive?  From the research I did, this command should work: `apt-ftparchive generate apt-ftparchive.conf` after you make the directories which contain the `.deb` files.

What errors do you get when running this command?

This site has a nice write up on how to set up apt-ftparchive to make the index file you need (read the section on Configuration Assimilation): http://nerdica.com/?p=43

Comment: I can already use the packages for installation (via apt-get and sources.list). To do this I've extracted the contents of the five installation ISOs and am serving them up via a webserver.

So the basic functionality is there. I just need to generate the Contents-ARCH.gz file - presumably one for each ISO. I looked at apt-ftparchive but it's poorly documented and I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I remember doing that once.  Are you sure you don't need the packages.gz file?

You can generate the packages.gz file using these commands:

cd location_of_repository

dpkg-scanpackages binary /dev/null | gzip -9c > binary/Packages.gz

Instructions are from this site:  http://mediakey.dk/~cc/howto-create-your-own-debian-or-ubuntu-package-repository/

Comment: The Packages.gz file contains only a list of package names, whereas Contents-ARCH.gz contains the contents of all packages. I'm pretty positive I need the latter for apt-file.

I'm coming to the conclusion it might be easier to generate the Contents file myself!

Comment: What is the error you get when you run the command: apt-ftparchive generate ?  This site may be of help for you: http://people.debian.org/~osamu/pub/po4a/html/ch02.en.html#_small_public_package_archive